# Oracle SQL: Alternative to nested REPLACE() in Select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT IncidentNumber, 
    ToiletType, 
    ToiletDangers,
    IncidentDate
FROM Core.LostLawsuits
```

...which returns the following results sort of like this:

```
+----------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| IncidentNumber | ToiletType | ToiletDangers             | Incident Date |
+----------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| 2100           | A          | Spontaneous Combustion    | 2/1/2016      |
+----------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| 2101           | P          | Attracts Bear Stampede    | 2/1/2016      |
+----------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------+
```

What I'd like to do is get the results, but change the ToiletType column result when outputting it. Currently, I am using a nested `REPLACE()`, and would like to know if there's a better / different way of doing this, **while maintaining a one column result for `ToiletType`**:

```
SELECT IncidentNumber, 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(ToiletType, 'A', 'Automatic Standard'), 'P', 'Portable Potty') as ToiletType,
    ToiletDangers,
    IncidentDate
FROM Core.LostLawsuits
```

Comment: I guess you don't have a ToiletTypeDescription table (ID, ToiletTypeId, Value).  That would be one way to handle this with a join.  Hardcoding text values is a maintenance nightmare

Comment: @kevinsky That is correct.

Comment: As these strings are not labels and they could change I call this a variety of business logic. Sure a Case expression works but every time there is a new value or if you want delivery in a different language you have to go back and change it.  Tables are free, at worst you could make a view with select 'A', 'Automatic Standard from dual union.....

Comment: @kevinsky I am in full agreement. However, requirements are what they are. :b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CASE expression would work for your example:

```
case ToiletType
   when 'A' then 'Automatic Standard'
   when 'P' then 'Portable Potty'
   end
```

i.e.

```
SELECT IncidentNumber, 
       case ToiletType
          when 'A' then 'Automatic Standard'
          when 'P' then 'Portable Potty'
       end as ToiletType,
       ToiletDangers,
       IncidentDate
FROM   Core.LostLawsuits
```

Perhaps better though would be to join to a ToiletTypes table?

Comment: This one works well so far. You might want to update to include parentheses between `CASE` and `END`, though.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo No parentheses are needed, in fact they would make the code invalid?

Comment: Hmm, dunno. Your code doesn't work for me. In fact, only this does: `(case ToiletType
   when 'A' then 'Automatic Standard'
   when 'P' then 'Portable Potty'
   end) as ToiletType`. Keep in mind, I am selecting multiple columns, and expect this result to be a column.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show the complete code, which will work without (or indeed with) the parentheses you are adding.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I was wrong earlier. It'll work either with or without parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I think you want `CASE`:

```
SELECT IncidentNumber, 
       (CASE ToiletType
            WHEN 'A' THEN 'Automatic Standard'
            WHEN 'P' THEN 'Portable Potty'
            ELSE ToiletType
        END) as ToiletType,
      ToiletDangers,
      IncidentDate
FROM Core.LostLawsuits;
```

Comment: @MarkBuffalo . . . I cannot see how this would produce two such columns.  Only one is named `ToiletType`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function but I doubt you will have any performance or readability improvements:

```
select 
  incidentnumber, 
  decode(ToiletteType, 'A', 'Automatic Standard', 'P', 'Portable Potty', ToiletteType),
  toiletdangers,
  incidentdate
from 
  core.lostlawsuits;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: In Oracle, there is also the `decode` function that could be used, as in

```
select decode(ToiletType, 'A', 'Automatic Standard', 
                          'P', 'Portable Potty', 
                          'Unknown Type '||ToiletType) ...
```

which causes a bit less typing than `CASE... WHEN... END`
but I prefer `CASE` anyway because it's ANSI SQL compatible.

Comment: I like this example. The `'Unknown_Type '||ToiletType` part is pretty clever. (Did you include a space on purpose, though?)

Comment: @MarkBuffalo Yes, the space is intentional, to make the output more readable in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The ToiletType should be a foreign key to a lookup table. The lookup table would contain at least two columns - a ToiletTypeCode and a ToiletTypeDescription. You would want a foreign key between your existing table and the new lookup table to ensure referential integrity.

Once that's in place, the query becomes trivial:

```
SELECT
    LL.IncidentNumber,
    TT.ToiletTypeDescription AS ToiletType,
    LL.ToiletDangers,
    LL.IncidentDate
FROM Core.LostLawsuits LL
INNER JOIN Core.ToiletTypes TT ON TT.ToiletTypeCode = LL.ToiletType
```

This also ensures that only valid Toilet Types are used in your LostLawsuits table.

Finally, it means that if a new ToiletType is added in the future it simply becomes a single `INSERT` statement to the ToiletTypes table instead of trying to hunt down every bit of code where you used some `CASE` or `REPLACE` statement to get descriptions.

Comment: Agreed. However, this is legacy stuff. Can't change the database. There is also no ToiletTypes tablet. I provided this as an example. Perhaps it was a bad example, then?